# How to fix "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rgba' " when using KivyMD to build an interface?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to learn app development using Python and KivyMD; I've been using the videos from Erik Sandberg on youtube as a tutorial, but he seems to be using the Kivy code from July 2019, which uses #import NavigationDrawer to get access to the Navigation Drawer functions. I've looked around the internet and found some solutions to help partially fix some of the issues that I have with accessing this simple function, but I've only gotten so far as to only be able to run the program in the code provided below. Once I drag the navigation bar across the screen, the app crashes and gives the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rgba'. Please let me know what I can do to fix this and get access to the navigation drawer functions, and if you know where I can find any tutorials that are based on the new version of Kivy, I'd really appreciate it!

Thanks so much!

**Code in main.py:**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp

class MainApp(MDApp): 
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Code in main.kv:**

```
NavigationLayout: 
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        title: "Actions"
    Button:
        text: "Hey!"
```

Relevant Images of Code:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Different things can produce a `None` object.  A function without an explicit `return` does that.  Some image loaders do that if they can't find the file.  `rgba` looks like an image attribute or method.  A `None` object does not have such an attribute.  Figure out why the code is producing a `None` at the problem point.  You many need to look at the full `traceback`.

Comment: I suspect you need to set `theme_cls` in your `MainApp`.

Answer (score 1):

The tutor of your video might be using **kivymd 0.1.4.2.Dev0** version of kivymd(from master branch). But in latest versions MDNavigationLayout has changed to NavigationLayout(). in your case installing kivymd from master branch will solve your problem. Also note that MDDropdownMenu only works with this Dev version.

But note that, there are some issues you may experience in future because, after you created apk file with kivymd Dev version the app will be runnig too slow on android devices. And sometimes icons in your app will not show up.

Answer (score 0):

Code to be changed in kv file:

```
NavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        Screen:
            Button:
                text: 'Hey!'
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        title: "Actions"
```